# Olbers paradox in different number of dimensions

Tags: geometry, physics

[Olber's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olbers%27s_paradox)

Consider an infinite and stationary universe with two spatial dimensions.

If the light from bright objects falls off at a rate of $1/d^2$ do you have a bright night sky?

In an actual 2 dimensional universe the fall of is $1/d$.  Do you get a bright night sky.

What about 1 dimension, 3 dimensions or 10 spatial dimensions?

Comment: It seems to me you've omitted the key aspect of Olber's paradox, which is that the distribution of "bright objects" is uniiform in space as well as brightness.  Possibly you mean to convey this by specifying "an infinite and stationary universe", but to make a mathematical problem out this one needs more explicit assumptions.

Answer (score 2):

In $n$ dimensions you expect the light to fall off as $\frac 1{d^{n-1}}$ because the area of an $n$ dimensional ball goes up as $d^{n-1}$.  If you follow through the normal Olbers argument, the fact that these exponents are equal leads to a constant amount of light reaching the observer from each $n$ dimensional spherical shell and you see a bright sky in all dimensions.